# Dynamic button generation in class with click signal

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to create a GUI where many buttons and QWidgets will be created later. Because this (I want to move it to single classes and this is where I have the problem that I can create a button but when I click on the button my code will not be executed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# Clas Mainwindow

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        createb(self)
        self.show()

# class that should create the buttons with click action so that when I create 
# the class the button is created with click action on the main window

class createb():
    def __init__(self, mainwindow):
        mainwindow.b = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Push Me')
        mainwindow.l = QtWidgets.QLabel('I have not been clicked yet')

        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()
        h_box.addWidget(mainwindow.l)
        h_box.addStretch()

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(mainwindow.b)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box)

        mainwindow.setLayout(v_box)
        mainwindow.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Lesson 5')

        mainwindow.b.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)
    def btn_click(self):
            self.l.setText('I have been clicked')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
a_window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Forgot the description:
I want to create a GUI where many buttons and QWidgets will be created later.  Because this (I want to move it to single classes and this is where I have the problem that I can create a button but when I click on the button my code will not be executed.

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal to see error messages ? I think you should get error because there is no `self.l` but `mainwindow.l`

Comment: no i didn't get an error message. If I replace self.l with mainwindow I get unresolved reference

Comment: because you should use `self.mainwindow = mainwindow` in `__init__` to have access to `self.mainwindow` in other methods in `createb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# Clas Mainwindow

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
#        createb(self)
        self.btnClick = createb(self)     # +

        self.show()

# class that should create the buttons with click action so that when I create  
# the class the button is created with click action on the main window

class createb():
    def __init__(self, mainwindow):                     
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow                       # <--- +
        mainwindow.b = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Push Me')
        mainwindow.l = QtWidgets.QLabel('I have not been clicked yet')

        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        h_box.addStretch()
        h_box.addWidget(mainwindow.l)
        h_box.addStretch()

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_box.addWidget(mainwindow.b)
        v_box.addLayout(h_box)

        mainwindow.setLayout(v_box)
        mainwindow.setWindowTitle('PyQt5 Lesson 5')

        mainwindow.b.clicked.connect(self.btn_click)

    def btn_click(self):
#            self.l.setText('I have been clicked')
            self.mainwindow.l.setText('I have been clicked')    # +

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
a_window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]